# Is a series of update_option calls safe, performance wise?

Tags: php, options

I have coded up a function that sets plenty of WordPress options in series.

For example:

```
update_option('option1', '0');
update_option('option2', '0');
update_option('option3', '0');
update_option('option4', '1');
update_option('option5', '1');
update_option('option6', '0');
update_option('option7', '1');
```

I understand that what this function does is change values in the database. I am aware that when using `get_option`, a form of caching takes place, so it could be considered safe. However, for `update_option`, I am not very sure.

I couldn't find a function like `update_option` that accepts multiple options to update. So is doing it like this good for performance? Is there another safer way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using separate option names for a bunch of related options is not ideal.

Instead, store options in a single key as a serialized array unless there is a specific reason not too. This way, you'll only need the one call to `add_option()`, `update_option()`, and `get_option()` which will mean fewer queries being generated overall, particularly (as you noted), when adding and updating values.

```
// Example function where options are saved under the name wpse242105_options
function wpse242105_options() {
    // Example settings array
    $settings = array (
        'option1' => '0',
        'option2' => '0',
        'option3' => '0',
        'option4' => '1',
        'option5' => '1',
        'option6' => '0',
        'option7' => '1',   
    );

    // Save all of the options under a single option key, wpse242105_options
    add_option( 'wpse242105_options', $settings ); // Using add_option() so option will be created if it doesn't exist.
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse242105_options' );
```

Once the options have been saved you can get them all in one call to `get_option()`.

```
 $saved_options = get_option( 'wpse242105_options' );
 print_r( $saved_options );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [option1] => 0
    [option2] => 0
    [option3] => 0
    [option4] => 1
    [option5] => 1
    [option6] => 0
    [option7] => 1
)
```

Note that WordPress will handle the serialization of the array for you. The `option_value` for `wpse242105_options` will look like this in the database:

```
a:7:{s:7:"option1";s:1:"1";s:7:"option2";s:1:"0";s:7:"option3";s:1:"0";s:7:"option4";s:1:"1";s:7:"option5";s:1:"1";s:7:"option6";s:1:"0";s:7:"option7";s:1:"1";}
```

`get_option()` will turn the serialized array back into a PHP array.

Comment: I've never thought of doing this. I'm guessing this is automatically stored as string, does `get_option` automatically convert it back to array?

Comment: Yes, `get_option()` will convert the serialized array into a PHP array automatically.

Comment: Alright, that sounds awesome! There are some I've disabled auto-load on though, looks like I'm gonna have to store two options.